# Law of conservation of energy: potential energy with and without generator

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, flow, dissipation

Forgive my knowledgeless, Iam foreign to physics, but this one bothers me for some time now..

We have water on a high ground, thus high potential energy.
Now we let the water flow down a valley. Where is the energy now? Is the water now warmer (As usual, when energy seem to be "lost")?

If yes, shouldn't it be possible to use this thermical energy to pump (almost, due to losses) all of the water up the hill again?

Second part of question:

We have the same amount of water which we let flow down into the valley, but this time, we have a generator to generate electrical energy while the water flows down. Since we pull out energy, the water now should be less warm than the first time, which would be contraintuitive since the generator adds frictional resistance.

Comment: Energy doesn't always mean heat, so don't only think about warm or cool. Regarding your first question, water is *flowing*, and yes even when you make it stop, the energy is dissipated, lost to environment, not just stored as thermal energy by water itself. Regarding your second question, we are nowhere near that much efficient to convert much part of the heat back to potential energy( Some heat will ALWAYS be used up by environment to increase total entropy). Regarding your last question, see my first statement.

Comment: Which other kind of energy could be created here if not heat? What do you mean by "energy dissipated, lost to environment"? When assumed that no evaporation of water occurs, I could only imagine infrared radiation.

Comment: I could only imagine infrared radiation or thermal conduction to the ground (which I both consider as "heat"). But yes, for example isolation with vacuumed double-walls will be hard if tons of water presses are to be beared.

Comment: Created is incorrect term. I was referring to the energy of water due to the virtue of its motion.(I know this is trivial, but you just mentioned heat). We are in a real world, no ideal conditions completely apply here. So can't energy from water be dissipated in its surroundings?( Refer to second law of thermodynamics ). Yes, if you completely isolate a water body( even if you don't take tons of water)  from its surroundings (by spending whole lot of useless extra effort) dissipation may be minimised, but can't be completely stopped (refer to ideal engine and efficiency factor of engines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the water now warmer ?

yes. The water falls down and bangs into the other water molecules. That adds motion to the molecules and that's heat. We can easily estimate by how much. Let's look at a liter if water with a mass of $m=1kg$ and drop height of $h = 10m$. The potential energy is $E = m \cdot g \ h$ which is about 98.1 Joules or call it 100 J for simplicty.

The specific heat of water is about 4 Joules/gram/degree. So the water heats up by $$\Delta T = \frac{100J }{1000g \cdot 4 J/gC} = 0.4C$$

So dropping water from a 10 meter height has only enough energy to heat up the water by 0.4 degrees Celsius (or Kelvin).

There is also heat exchange with the air, evaporation, drops blow of by wind, that can also play a role here.

> If yes, shouldn't it be possible to use this thermical energy to pump (almost, due to losses) all of the water up the hill again?

No. It's technically extremely difficult to harvest this very small temperature increase for anything.

> the water now should be less warm than the first time,

Yes. The generator slows down the water quite a bit so the impact of the falling water into the standing water is a lot weaker so it generates less heat.